# cannot import name 'Flask'

Tags: python, web, flask

Im using window 10, I did the command pip install flask but I kept getting a ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask'. When I worked with flask couple months back it was running fine. Came back to run my old programs today and i get this error? I was just trying to run a simple html website.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

app.static_folder = 'static'

@app.route('/')
def index():

return render_template('index.html')


if __name__=='__main__':
app.run(debug = True)
```

Also before this error I had No module named 'Flask' so I did(found this in other stackoverflow post):
1. virtualenv
2. pip install flask (getting output that requirements are already satisfied)
3. Then I just try to run my flask which is called i.py and I get cannot import name 'Flask'. Went through many solutions on here still no idea how to fix it.

Comment: If you start python.exe from your virtualenv, can you `import flask`? Can you `from flask import Flask`?

Comment: What version of python are you using / trying to use, have you updated since you last used Flask and therefore need to update Flask?

Comment: Have you named one of your scripts `flask.py`? If so, rename it.

Comment: @9000 Yeah I can import Flask.
3.6. Im not sure how would I go with updating Flask?
no scripts named flask.py

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1 in <module>
NameError: name 'flask' is not defined

Comment: Have you installed flask?

Comment: Fixed it, i had 2 versions of python 3.6 and 3.5.2 when I deleted 3.6 its working fine.

Answer (score -2):

Basically i had 2 versions of python 3.6 and 3.5.2 when I deleted 3.6 its working fine.